# how to split the array of object into different object on the basis of key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the data in this format

```
[{
    "Consumer": [{
        "Associated ID": "JSUDB2LXXX / BIC 7503 / US",
        "Parent Consumer": "7503"
    }],
    "Owner": [{
        "Entity": "EN",
        "Region": "LA"
    }]
}]
```

I want to convert in into the below format, I have to add title and value as the new key to the old key and value and have to separate each old key value in a separate object.

```
[{
    "Consumer": [{
            "title": "Associated ID",
            "name": "JSUDB2LXXX / BIC 7503 / US"
        },
        {
            "title": "Parent Consumer",
            "name": "7503"
        }
    ],
    "Owner": [{
            "title": "Entity",
            "name": "EN"
        },
        {
            "title": "Region",
            "name": "LA"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps:

```
let data = [{
    "Consumer": [{
        "Associated ID": "JSUDB2LXXX / BIC 7503 / US",
        "Parent Consumer": "7503"
    }],
    "Owner": [{
        "Entity": "EN",
        "Region": "LA"
    }]
}]

let final = []
data.forEach(el => {
  Object.keys(el).forEach(key => {
    let values = []
    Object.entries(el[key][0]).forEach(entry => {
      values.push({title: entry[0], name: entry[1]})
    })
    let newElement = {}
    newElement[key] = values
    final.push(newElement)
  })
})
console.log(final)
```

You can try it here :

https://jsbin.com/wazuyoyidi/edit?js,console

Comment: yes, it worked like a charm thank you. @MarcSanchez

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach.

```
const results = data.map((firstLevel) => {
  const finalObject = {};
  Object.entries(firstLevel).forEach(([name, array]) => {
    finalObject[name] = array
      .map((obj) =>
        Object.entries(obj).map(([title, name]) => ({ title, name }))
      )
      .flat();
  });
  return finalObject;
});
```

[https://jsbin.com/rafinobexa/edit?js,console][1]